# Azure Virtual Machine Extension file URL location with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm

Question is a little confusing but I will explain what I am doing.  I am building a new Azure VM in Terraform and calling a script inside of a virtual machine extension.  It is a basic powershell script.  The issue is, I am currently calling it from a public GitHub account.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "winrm" {
  name                  = "winrm"
  location              = var.location
  resource_group_name   = var.rg_name
  count                 = length(var.vm_name_suffix)
  virtual_machine_name  = azurerm_virtual_machine.vm[count.index].name
  publisher             = "Microsoft.Compute"
  type                  = "CustomScriptExtension"
  type_handler_version  = "1.9"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
  {
    "fileUris": ["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<name>/master/winrm.ps1"], 
    "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File \"./winrm.ps1\""
  }
  SETTINGS
}
```

Trying to figure out if there is a way I can call this from somewhere more secure.  I have this set up in an Azure DevOps repo but I am not sure how to pass any kind of authentication into the settings block.  I could also put this on a private GitHub account but again I would need to provide a way to authenticate to the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#extension-schema), you could include data in a `protectedSettings`, and Azure VM extension protected setting data is encrypted, and only decrypted on the target virtual machine.

> You can store sensitive data in a protected configuration, which is
>   encrypted and only decrypted inside the virtual machine. The protected
>   configuration is useful when the execution command includes secrets
>   such as a password.

In this case, it's recommended to upload your scripts into blob storage, then call the extension file from that storage account with storage account key.

For example:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "winrm" {
...

  settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "fileUris": ["https://mystorageaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/postdeploystuff/winrm.ps1"]
    }
SETTINGS
  protected_settings = <<PROTECTED_SETTINGS
    {
      "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -NonInteractive -File winrm.ps1",
      "storageAccountName": "mystorageaccountname",
      "storageAccountKey": "xxxxx"
    }
  PROTECTED_SETTINGS

  depends_on = ["azurerm_virtual_machine.vm[count.index].name"]


}
```

For more details, you could refer to [blog](https://jackstromberg.com/2018/11/using-terraform-with-azure-vm-extensions/) about using Terraform with Azure VM extensions.

Comment: Thank you for the response Nancy.  I will create a Storage Account and give this a shot.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks again